# Filtering DataTable based on column data and assign it to DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, datagridview, filter

I have a sqlite database connected to a `DataTable` and the `DataTable` is bound to a datagridview.

I have a column named Event Type and i want to separate the Event Types into two different datagridviews.

The first datagridview will contain all rows that have an Event Type other than "Exam" and the second datagridview will have ONLY rows that contain the Event Type "Exam".

I have been reading on filters but haven't got anything to work and am not sure the best way to approach this problem.

The datagridviews are both bound to the same `DataTable`.
I am fairly new to programming and am working on a personal app just trying to get used to c# and .NET.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this problem?

This code gave me the most progress, except that it makes all the current rows just go to blanks. It doesn't save it to the database or anything.

```
    public void EventTypeFilter()
    {
        var myDataView = dataSourceDataSet.Event.DefaultView;
        EventsDataGridView.DataSource = myDataView;
        myDataView.RowFilter = string.Format("EventType <> '{0}'", "Exam");   
    }
```

Comment: Could you please try and explain what you are trying to do and what the problem is a little better. For example what do you mean when you say the current rows just go to blanks? The code you have should work perfectly for filtering a data view. The best thing would be if you give the entire .cs file of a minimal example with only the code necessary to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I am just creating a simple task manager for school so you the user can input Events (assignments,exams,meetings,reviews,lab, etc) and I have two datagridviews, One is labeled current events which i want all events in EXCEPT the eventType "Exam". In the Second DatagridView labeled upcoming will hold all the events that HAVE a eventtype "Exam". So overall, i just want the events sorted out into the 2 datagrids. The problem with the code above is instead of filtering the entries it will make all the events regardless what the event is...go blank(each event removed from the grid but not the   db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

```
public void EventTypeFilter()
{
    DataTable table = dataSourceDataSet.Tables["TableName"];        
    table.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("EventType <> '{0}'", "Exam");
    EventsDataGridView.DataSource = table;           
}
```

Comment: I tried it and I still got the same issue :/ It clears all the rows with blank entries rather than just the rows that have an eventtype "Exam". Does it clear like that if the rowfilter is wrong or something?

Comment: try with this expression `myDataView.RowFilter = string.Format("EventType = '{0}'", "Exam");`

Comment: I was just thinking that as well, but unfortunately we still get the same result (blank entries).

Comment: did you try with out any filters?

Comment: what do you mean? without filters it will add all the event types fine but it doesnt filter "exam" like i want it to

Comment: Your code worked it was a mess up on my part, I have to put the [] around Event Type